Trying to fix gamedata, A.callback(f), is all I get back, local is also undefined so I cannot adjust data
So, I decided to play a certain Pokemon rogue game, and had initially decided to add only one thing to the games data which worked thanks to a Youtube tutorial and F12 on the page. But after said change, the game has given me an error which it only gives me as: A.callback(f),
Also, the local is now undefined, making it impossible to do anything with it.
I would like some answers and help to alleviate the issue. I'm also not too well versed with coding so you might need to dumb it down for me.
Thanks.
Tried F12 on the game page, went to console, typed in this.scene.gamedata.vouchers where it brought me to the line of code, paused the game and simply went to the local files which was available at the time. I added 10 vouchers like I was told to do in the video and then got the error.
This is the video I followed if it helps any.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SufDVb1q2is&t=101s&ab_channel=Smilinreap

this.step = C(function h(f) { your text                           A.callback(f), A.isRunning && (A.timeOutID = window.requestAnimationFrame(h)) }, "step"),

Sorry, I don't exactly know what else to add to help the situation, as I said I'm not well versed in coding.
